# Disable Dismissible without removing it from Widgettree

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Page with a large `image` in the center. This image has zoom functionality but i also want the option to drag the `image` down to pop the page.
I have tried to make it work with the `Dismissible` widget. The popping works the way i want, but the `Dismissible` dragging interferes with the zooming(dragging down for panning the image dismisses the page). 
I have tried setting the `direction:` to null while zooming, but that throws loads of warnings and still stops the panning some of the time.
I also tried to just rebuild without the `Dismissible` while zooming, but that will stop the first zoom gesture because of the rebuild, and the image also flickers for a brief moment while rebuilding.

So my question: Does anyone know of a way to suppress the dismissible while zooming, or a completely different approach to get this result.

Thank you very much.

```
Dismissible(
              key: Key("qwe"),
              direction: DismissDirection.down,
              onDismissed: (direction) => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                color: Colors.transparent,
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                child: PhotoView(
                  scaleStateChangedCallback: (scaleState) {
                    //can work with scaling callbacks here
                  },
                  customSize: Size(500, 500),
                  minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 1.0,
                  maxScale: 1.5,
                  imageProvider: NetworkImage(widget.url),
                  backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use confirmDismiss parameter in Dismissible and return false, example:

```
Dismissible(
      confirmDismiss: (direction) async {
          return null;
      },),
```